NodeJS put socket.io on-Events to different file
Hi i want to organise my code a little better and want to split all my socket.on() events into multiple files.
Right now this is my setup. Everything is in index.mjs.
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('event1', function (member) {
        // do smth
    });

    socket.on('event2', function (member) {
        // do smth
    });

});

What i want to do is something like this
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    require("./events/1.mjs");

    require("./events/2.mjs");

});

But i get the following error:

require() of ES Module ./events/1.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of ./events/1.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

I tried to somehow use the import statement but i honestly dont know how the ./events/1.mjs file would need to look like. I tried googling and other posts and forums but couldnt get it to work which is frustrating

Export a function from those modules, then call those functions from the connection handler.

Have you tried giving it a name?
Example
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   const events_1 = require("./events/1.mjs");
});

Here you are using mjs file extension. So you can't use require, you have to change your project to module.
Example usage is as follows
example.mjs
export function myfunction() {
 console.log('Hello from a module!');
}

to use;
import { myFunction } from './myModule.mjs';


"you can't use require" - if you already know that, why start with "Have you tried giving it a name?" and an invalid example nonetheless?
